# When i try to use Spring and file.properties, i see error

Tags: java, spring

I try to use Spring with file.properties, but i see error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
 Configuration problem: Configuration problem: Id is required for element 'properties' when used as a top-level tag
Offending resource: class path resource [di.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [di.xml]
```

What should I do?
I have:
**Java class**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Value
@Component("person")
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class SimplePerson implements Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("20")
    int age;
    Contact contact;
}
```

**Spring .xml file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="cours"/>

<util:properties  location="classpath:person.properties"/>

<!--<bean class="java.lang.Integer" id="age" c:value="18"/>-->
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="firstName" c:value="${firstName}" />
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="lastName" c:value="${lastName}"/>
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="type" c:value="telephone"/>
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="value" c:value="0504540"/>
```

**file.properties**

```
firstName=Roma
lastName=Izmailov
age=20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add id attribute to util:properties:

```
<util:properties id="someId" location="classpath:person.properties"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn`t help

Comment: I hope "file.properties" mentioned in the end of Your question is justa typo for "person.properties" mentioned in bean configuration. Can You please check it?

Comment: I wrote in .xml file "person.properties"

Comment: Yes, I see. But in the properties file content You wrote is marked as "file.properties"